# MongoDB, Monk, findAndModify not upserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I have this function in a node project that is supposed to update or create a new entry based on whether the slug matches. It updates perfectly so the response being returned is correct but it won't insert a new item and I'm not sure what I've missed.

MongoDB version 3.0.4 (installed via Homebrew)
Mac OSX Yosemite
MongoDB Node package 2.0.39
Monk 1.0.1

```
collection.findAndModify({
      "query": { "slug": pluginslug },
      "update":
        {
            "slug"            : pluginslug,
            "name"            : response.data.name,
            "current_version" : response.data.version,
            "description"     : response.data.short_description,
            "change_log"      : response.data.sections.changelog,
            "updated"         : response.data.last_updated,
            "tested"          : response.data.tested
        },
      "upsert" :true,
      "new" : true
      }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
          console.log(doc)
          res.redirect("plugins/new");
        }
    });
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Yes of couse someone already anwered `$set`, which is how you should be doing it but it of course **does not solve** your "upsert" problem. Clearly your have "multiple" items that match the "slug" you are passing in. I would suggest that "more than just that" constitute a "unique" record to you. Therefore, include **all** of the keys that mean "unique" in your "query" porttion. That means when those "do not match" then you get an "new" record. I'd answer like this, but you don't give a clear data example to be sure of. Best ask that way next time.

Comment: I promise you it's not a multiple item issue. It works fine if the record exists, not if it doesn't. This is a very early proof of concept and I know for sure which records exist in the database. and slug is indeed unique. Again, thanks for trying.

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: version 3.0.4 Will add more details to the question.

Comment: Will update my answer, pls try do this, i was have perfect result with upsert and updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the correct answer here: [Issue with a simple mongo/monk findAndModify query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529471/issue-with-a-simple-mongo-monk-findandmodify-query?rq=1)

The solution is to provide the options as an own object (it is not well documented by the monk docs):

```
db.test.findAndModify(
{
  "query": { "slug": "1234512345" },
  "update":
    {
        "$set": 
        {
            "slug"            : "1234512345",
            "name"            : "response.data.name",
            "current_version" : "response.data.version",
            "description"     : "response.data.short_description",
            "change_log"      : "response.data.sections.changelog",
            "updated"         : "response.data.last_updated",
            "tested"          : "response.data.teste"
        }
    }
},
{
  "upsert" :true,
  "new" : true
}, 
function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(doc);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
collection.findAndModify({
      "query": { "slug": pluginslug },
      "update":
        {
          $set:{
            "slug"            : pluginslug,
            "name"            : response.data.name,
            "current_version" : response.data.version,
            "description"     : response.data.short_description,
            "change_log"      : response.data.sections.changelog,
            "updated"         : response.data.last_updated,
            "tested"          : response.data.tested
           } 
       },
      "upsert" :true,
      "new" : true
      }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
          console.log(doc)
          res.redirect("plugins/new");
        }
    });
```

Try pls run this code:

```
"use strict";
var mongojs = require("mongojs");

var collections = ["test"];

var db = mongojs('test', collections);

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.test.findAndModify({
      "query": { "slug": "1234512345" },
      "update":
        {
            "slug"            : "1234512345",
            "name"            : "response.data.name",
            "current_version" : "response.data.version",
            "description"     : "response.data.short_description",
            "change_log"      : "response.data.sections.changelog",
            "updated"         : "response.data.last_updated",
            "tested"          : "response.data.teste"
        },
      "upsert" :true,
      "new" : true
      }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log(doc);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Upvoted not because it worked, but because you're right and I should have done $set to begin with.

Comment: Straight as it is it throws an error on the db.on line saying object test has no on method. Commenting out that line it just sits there and does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably too late but I just stumbled upon this question and having faced a similar issue, here is what worked for me:

```
collection.findAndModify(
  { "slug": pluginslug }
  ,[]
  ,{
      $set:{
        "slug"            : pluginslug,
        "name"            : response.data.name,
        "current_version" : response.data.version,
        "description"     : response.data.short_description,
        "change_log"      : response.data.sections.changelog,
        "updated"         : response.data.last_updated,
        "tested"          : response.data.tested
       } 
   }
  ,{"upsert" :true,"new" : true}
  , function (err, doc) {
    //..something here... 
   });
```

The findAndModify method documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) should help.

Answer (score -1):

Try somethink like below

```
router.post('/login/:id', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('user');
console.log(req.body);
collection.findAndModify({userid : req.params.id}, { $set: req.body } ,    {upsert : true}, function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(
        (err === null) ? {msg: 'success'} : {msg: 'error: ' + err}
        );
    });
});
```