# Issue with a simple mongo/monk findAndModify query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert, monk

Just a note I am fairly new to mongo and more notably very new to using node/js.

I'm trying to write a query to insert new documents or update already existing documents in my collection.

The proposed structure of the collection is:

`{ _id: xxxxxxx, ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxxx", date: "xx-xx-xx xxxx" }`

Note that my intention is a store an fixed length int for the _id rather than the internal ObjectId (is this possible/considered bad practice?). The int is guaranteed to be unique and comes from another source.

```
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/cgo_schedule');

var insertDocuments = function(db, match) {
    var db = db;
    var collection = db.get('cgo_schedule');
    collection.findAndModify(
      {
        "query": { "_id": match.matchId },
        "update": { "$set": { 
            "ip": match.ip,
            "date": match.date
            },
        "$setOnInsert": {
          "_id": match.matchId,
        }},
        "options": { "new": true, "upsert": true }
      },
      function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( doc );
      }
  );
}
```

This doesn't work at all however. It doesn't insert anything to the database, but it also gives no errors, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The output (for `console.log (doc)`) is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Monk docs aren't much help, but according to the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/blob/master/lib/collection.js#L254), the `options` object must be provided as a separate parameter.

So your call should look like this instead:

```
collection.findAndModify(
    {
        "query": { "_id": match.matchId },
        "update": { 
            "$set": { 
                "ip": match.ip, 
                "date": match.date 
            }
        }
    },
    { "new": true, "upsert": true },
    function(err,doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( doc );
    }
);
```

Note that I removed the `$setOnInsert` part as the `_id` is always included on insert with an upsert.